# Elasticsearch: alternative to cross_fields with fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index with the *standard* analyzer. I would like to perfom search queries containing multiple words, e.g. **human anatomy**. This search should be performed across several fields:

1. Title
2. Subject
3. Description

All the words in the query should be present in any of the fields (e.g. 'human' in title and 'anatomy' in description, etc.). If not all the words are present across these fields, the result shouldn't be returned.

Now, more importantly, I want to get fuzzy matches (for example, these queries should return approximately the same results as *human anatomy*:

- *human anatom*
- *human anatomic*
- *humanic anatomic*
- etc.

So fuzziness should apply **to every word** in the query.

As [Elasticsearch doesn't support fuzziness for the multi-match cross-fields queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields), I have been trying to achieve the desired behaviour this way:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool" : {
        "must": [
            {
                "query": {
                    "bool":
                        {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "title": {
                                            "query": "human",
                                            "fuzziness": 2,
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "description": {
                                            "query": "human",
                                            "fuzziness": 2,
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "subject": {
                                            "query": "human",
                                            "fuzziness": 2,
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                            ]
                        }
                }
            },
            {
                "query": {
                    "bool":
                        {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "title": {
                                            "query": "anatomy",
                                            "fuzziness": 2,
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "description": {
                                            "query": "anatomy",
                                            "fuzziness": 2,
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "subject": {
                                            "query": "anatomy",
                                            "fuzziness": 2,
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                            ]
                        }
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
}
```

The idea behind this code is the following: find the results where

1. *either of the fields* contains *human* (with 2-letter edit distance, e.g.: *humane, humon, humanic*, etc.)
   **and**
2. *either of the fields* contains *anatomy* (with 2-letter edit distance, e.g.: *anatom, anatomic*, etc.).

Unfortunately, this code does not work and fails to retrieve a great number of relevant results.  For example (the edit distance between each of the words in the two queries <= 2):

- *human anatomic* – 0 results
- *humans anatomy* – 21 results

How can I make fuzziness work within the given conditions? Recreating the index with n-gram is currently not an option, so I would like to make fuzziness work.

Comment: Have you tried [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html)? It would populate some hidden field while indexing and then you can run any fuzzy searches against it.

Comment: @ilvar As I said in the question, recreating the index is not an option, just as using a single field where all the other fields would be copied. I am aware of this possibility but here I am primarily interested in how to mimic the fuzziness behaviour in the given condition.